# How do I size components inside of a scrollview using flex in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am confused as to how flex is used inside of a ScrollView. I am trying to use flex to size all the components inside of my ScrollView, but every time I add another component inside the ScrollView, the others get shorter. This would make sense in a normal View, but I want the new added components to 'overflow' to the bottom of the ScrollView so I can scroll to them and have the other components remain the same size. Is there a way to do this using flex inside a ScrollView, or do I need to set the height of each component in the ScrollView manually?

Below is my code. The components that I am referring to are the MainCard components inside the ScrollView.

Thank you for your help.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
  Dimensions,
  ScrollView,
} from 'react-native';
import {vw, vh} from 'react-native-viewport-units';
import Header from '../components/UI/Header';
import PageTitle from '../components/UI/PageTitle';
import Navbar from '../components/UI/Navbar';
import TallCard from '../components/UI/TallCard';
import MainCard from '../components/UI/MainCard';
import Carousel from '../components/UI/Carousel';

class UserHome extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.page}>
        <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
          <Header text="Workouts" textVisible={false} />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.titleContainer}>
          <PageTitle text="Workouts" />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.navbarContainer}>
          <Navbar />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.scrollContainer}>
          <ScrollView
            contentContainerStyle={{
              alignItems: 'center',
              flex: 1,
              flexGrow: 1,
            }}>
            <View style={styles.mainCardContainer}>
              <MainCard
                title="Rutina Diaria"
                subtitle="Ab Circuit"
                img="https://imagesvc.meredithcorp.io/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fstatic.onecms.io%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fsites%2F35%2F2017%2F01%2F03212351%2Ffitness-model-promo.jpg"
              />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.mainCardContainer}>
              <MainCard
                title="Rutina Diaria"
                subtitle="Ab Circuit"
                img="https://imagesvc.meredithcorp.io/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fstatic.onecms.io%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fsites%2F35%2F2017%2F01%2F03212351%2Ffitness-model-promo.jpg"
              />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.mainCardContainer}>
              <MainCard
                title="Rutina Diaria"
                subtitle="Ab Circuit"
                img="https://imagesvc.meredithcorp.io/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fstatic.onecms.io%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fsites%2F35%2F2017%2F01%2F03212351%2Ffitness-model-promo.jpg"
              />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.mainCardContainer}>
              <MainCard
                title="Rutina Diaria"
                subtitle="Ab Circuit"
                img="https://imagesvc.meredithcorp.io/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fstatic.onecms.io%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fsites%2F35%2F2017%2F01%2F03212351%2Ffitness-model-promo.jpg"
              />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.mainCardContainer}>
              <MainCard
                title="Rutina Diaria"
                subtitle="Ab Circuit"
                img="https://imagesvc.meredithcorp.io/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fstatic.onecms.io%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fsites%2F35%2F2017%2F01%2F03212351%2Ffitness-model-promo.jpg"
              />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.mainCardContainer}>
              <MainCard
                title="Rutina Diaria"
                subtitle="Ab Circuit"
                img="https://imagesvc.meredithcorp.io/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fstatic.onecms.io%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fsites%2F35%2F2017%2F01%2F03212351%2Ffitness-model-promo.jpg"
              />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.mainCardContainer}>
              <MainCard
                title="Rutina Diaria"
                subtitle="Ab Circuit"
                img="https://imagesvc.meredithcorp.io/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fstatic.onecms.io%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fsites%2F35%2F2017%2F01%2F03212351%2Ffitness-model-promo.jpg"
              />
            </View>
          </ScrollView>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.fill} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  page: {flex: 1},
  headerContainer: {
    paddingTop: 50,
    flex: 2,
  },
  titleContainer: {flex: 1.7, paddingLeft: 20},
  navbarContainer: {flex: 2, paddingLeft: 25},
  scrollContainer: {
    flex: 17,
  },

  mainCardContainer: {
    flex: 20,
    paddingTop: 35,
    paddingLeft: 15,
  },
  fill: {flex: 0},
});

export default UserHome;
```

Comment: Just don't add flex to the scrollview.

Comment: Do you mean remove 'flex:1' and/or 'flexGrow:1' from the contentContainerStyle of the ScrollView? If so, unfortunately, this does not change anything.

Comment: Also remove  the ```ScrollContainer``` view, too. It is useless.

Comment: Okay, but then how would I set the height of the entire ScrollView using flex. Right now it is being done with the 'flex:17' style being applied to ScrollContainer. If I remove ScrollContainer, the ScrollView no longer has the same height.

Comment: ```<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    ...
  </View>
</ScrollView>```

Comment: don't use flex box use height of the window or the screen to make it responsive check this snack example https://snack.expo.io/xUj01E3Yy

Comment: That worked, thank you Ashwith. So is it a general rule to not use flex box to size items inside a ScrollView then?